# How to arrange the order of bars in geom_bar

Tags: r, bar-chart, geom-bar

For this week's `TidyTuesday` challenge on the Erasmus dataset, I was trying to replicate a visualization that seemed cool to me. Yet, I had faced an issue with the ordering of columns in a bar plot and I specifically wanted to ask about a nuance that I could not grasp, although I solved it.

In this first visualization, the coloring of bars was based on their order with regard to their letters.

[image]

In the second one, the coloring was based on their order with regard to their total participants.

[image]

This all changed thanks to the following code when cleaning data.

`mutate(country_name = factor(country_name, levels = rev(country_name)))`

Here is also the whole code chunk;

```
 filter (receiving_country_code == "TR") %>%
 filter (sending_country_code != receiving_country_code) %>%
 group_by(sending_country_code) %>%
 summarize(total = sum(participants)) %>%
 arrange(desc(total)) %>%
 filter(total>9) %>%
 left_join(country_codes, by = c("sending_country_code" = "iso2c")) %>%
 mutate(country_name = case_when(
   sending_country_code == "UK" ~ "United Kingdom",
   sending_country_code == "EL" ~ "Greece",
   TRUE ~ country_name
 )) %>%
 mutate(country_name = factor(country_name, levels = rev(country_name)))

p1 <- ggplot(data = top_incoming,
           aes(x = country_name, y = total, fill = country_name)) +
 geom_bar(width = 0.3, stat = "identity", show.legend = FALSE) +
 geom_text(aes(x = country_name, y = 0, label = paste0(country_name, " - ", total)),
           hjust = 1.05, size = 2, colour = rep(c("#173f5f", "#3caea3"), 10)) +
 coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0) +
 ylim(c(0, 40)) +
 scale_fill_manual(values = rep(c("#3caea3", "#173f5f"), 10)) +
 labs(title = "Incoming Students",
      subtitle = "2015-2019") +
 theme_void() +
 theme (plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, family = "subtitle", size = 14),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5, family = "subtitle", size = 12),
        plot.caption = element_text(family = "caption"))
```

This all changed thanks to the following code when cleaning data.
Although I figured out what this code's function is, I could not understand its underlying logic, particularly what `levels = rev(country_name)` means considering that the order of the columns was primarily based on character level and, at best, I think, the  `rev()` function should have reversed it instead of changing the order to be based on participants.

Comment: Could you provide the code for the graph as well?

Comment: of course I can. Apologize for not adding this here as the character limit did not allow me but I put the whole code chunk in the question. I hope it can work. Thank for your attention beforehand.